# Rasa bot bad request and cors proxy issue

Tags: node.js, ajax, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Rasa core version 13.7
 nlu version 14.6
os windows 10
python version 3.5

i created rasa chatbot and trained nlu as well as dialogue model.i have manage to run this bot successfully in the console but when we try to run this as the http server we get a cors proxy error as follows
the command we used to run the server is

- python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/default/stem_nlu --enable_api --credentials credentials.yml --cors "*"
  i have also tried
- python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/default/stem_nlu --enable_api --credentials credentials.yml --cors "*" -c rest 
  with no luck

  i have also tried

  - python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu/default/stem_nlu --enable_api --credentials credentials.yml --cors "*" -c rest 
    with no luck
    i tried sending request through browser and postman to

    localhost:5005/conversations/deafult/respond i got
       {
      "code": 400,
      "details": {
    "in": "query",
    "parameter": "query"
       },
     "help": null,
      "message": "Missing the message parameter.",
      "reason": "InvalidParameter",
      "status": "failure",
      "version": "0.13.7"
    }

and also tried

```
       localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook
```

i got

```
     Bad Request
     The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

bot server shows

```
       options 127.0.0.1 - - [2019-04-15 17:34:30] "OPTIONS /webhooks/rest/webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 306 0.001031
```

then post request

```
     127.0.0.1 - - [2019-04-15 17:34:30] "POST /webhooks/rest/webhook 
  HTTP/1.1" 400 352 0.000000
```

and we have used script as follows
        $(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#button").click(function(){
var message=document.getElementById("message").value;
 console.log(message);
$.ajaxSetup({
 headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
 });

$.ajax({
 url: "http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook",
 type: "POST",
 data: '{ "sender": message}'
 }).done(function(data) {

    console.log(data);
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly mention that CORS needs to accept all API calls. Go to the RASA project folder and run the following:

```
rasa run --enable-api --cors "*"
```

Now you will not see *cors* error.